# Object is lost due to node failure while using DatasetPipeline and Actors on WSL2

Tags: python, ray

I'm new to ray.io and I ran into an issue while playing around with it that I'm having trouble debugging. Full stack trace enclosed below. Figured I'd try SO before opening up an actual bug since I don't know what I don't know yet. Github repo to repro the issue here: https://github.com/naddeoa/rayio-bug-repro.

```
2021-10-06 22:28:11,383 WARNING worker.py:1215 -- A worker died or was killed while executing a task by an unexpected system error. To troubleshoot the problem, check the logs for the dead worker. RayTask ID: ae02b9ead87c9b111d608eaf1ffa6bf7c46c3c9a0ccc6498 Worker ID: cc30edf2998ff359da14355e58a6cb9c25cbe007173bb5138873b85c Node ID: 1af1653fd05d12b6912493cede6d000369a28526a5edbcccca05f3f9 Worker IP address: 172.28.74.251 Worker port: 37783 Worker PID: 20899
(pid=20899) *** SIGSEGV received at time=1633584491 on cpu 0 ***
(pid=20899) PC: @     0x7f54149bd8e0  (unknown)  ray::core::CoreWorkerDirectTaskReceiver::HandleTask()::{lambda()#1}::operator()()
(pid=20899)     @     0x7f5416296210  910758128  (unknown)
(pid=20899)     @     0x7f54149be05a         80  std::_Function_handler<>::_M_invoke()
(pid=20899)     @     0x7f541493f705        448  ray::core::NormalSchedulingQueue::ScheduleRequests()
(pid=20899)     @     0x7f5414cfd1b6        112  boost::asio::detail::completion_handler<>::do_complete()
(pid=20899)     @     0x7f5414dffa28        112  boost::asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one()
(pid=20899)     @     0x7f5414e005e1        160  boost::asio::detail::scheduler::run()
(pid=20899)     @     0x7f5414e02130         64  boost::asio::io_context::run()
(pid=20899)     @     0x7f54149a9fd5        144  ray::core::CoreWorkerProcess::RunTaskExecutionLoop()
(pid=20899)     @     0x7f5414846c17         32  __pyx_pw_3ray_7_raylet_10CoreWorker_9run_task_loop()
(pid=20899)     @           0x50506b  (unknown)  (unknown)
(pid=20899)     @           0x908780  (unknown)  (unknown)
Stage 0: 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  1.35it/s]
(pid=20898) logging
(pid=20892) logging
(pid=20894) logging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 146, in <module>
    main_pipeline_actor()
  File "main.py", line 27, in timerfn
    fn()
  File "main.py", line 74, in main_pipeline_actor
    results = ray.get([actor.log_from_pipeline.remote() for actor in actors])
  File "/home/anthony/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/hello-ray-O1YdFran-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py", line 82, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anthony/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/hello-ray-O1YdFran-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1621, in get
    raise value.as_instanceof_cause()
ray.exceptions.RayTaskError: ray::RemotePipelineActor.log_from_pipeline() (pid=20892, ip=172.28.74.251, repr=<main.RemotePipelineActor object at 0x7efdc83e1160>)
  File "main.py", line 62, in log_from_pipeline
    for df in self.pipeline.iter_batches(batch_size=1000, batch_format="pandas"):
  File "/home/anthony/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/hello-ray-O1YdFran-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/data/dataset_pipeline.py", line 97, in gen_batches
    for batch in ds.iter_batches(
  File "/home/anthony/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/hello-ray-O1YdFran-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/data/dataset.py", line 1016, in iter_batches
    block = ray.get(block_window[0])
ray.exceptions.ObjectLostError: Object 69a6825d641b4613ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100000001000000 is lost due to node failure.
(pid=20892) 2021-10-06 22:28:12,185     WARNING worker.py:1619 -- Local object store memory usage:
(pid=20892)
(pid=20892) (global lru) capacity: 1000000000
(pid=20892) (global lru) used: 0%
(pid=20892) (global lru) num objects: 0
(pid=20892) (global lru) num evictions: 0
(pid=20892) (global lru) bytes evicted: 0
```

The logs are kind of difficult to use as well. There are dozens and dozens of logs and none of them seem to have a smoking gun. Here are a few things I found. One in `raylet.out`

```
22[2021-10-06 22:29:06,902 W 20070 20070] pull_manager.cc:525: Object neither in memory nor external storage 69a6825d641b4613ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100000001000000
23[2021-10-06 22:29:06,902 W 20070 20070] pull_manager.cc:466: Size of object 69a6825d641b4613ffffffffffffffffffffffff0100000001000000 stored in object store is zero. This may be a bug since objects in the object store should be large, and can result in too many objects being fetched to this node
```

and one in `redis-shard_0.out`

520009:M 06 Oct 2021 22:27:29.819 #

```
Server can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
620009:M 06 Oct 2021 22:27:29.819 # Current maximum open files is 4096. maxclients has been reduced to 4064 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
```

And of course, here is the code I'm trying to run.

```py
import ray
from typing import List
from ray.data.dataset_pipeline import DatasetPipeline

data_files = ["data/data1.csv", "data/data2.csv", "data/data3.csv"]


@ray.remote
class RemotePipelineActor:
    def __init__(self, pipeline: DatasetPipeline) -> None:
        self.pipeline = pipeline

    def log_from_pipeline(self) -> List[bytes]:
        for df in self.pipeline.iter_batches(batch_size=1000, batch_format="pandas"):
            pass

        return 1


def main_pipeline_actor():
    pipelines = ray.data.read_csv(data_files).pipeline(parallelism=3).split(3)

    actors = [RemotePipelineActor.remote(pipeline) for pipeline in pipelines]
    results = ray.get([actor.log_from_pipeline.remote() for actor in actors])

    return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ray.init()
    main_pipeline_actor()
```

Am I just using pipelines wrong in this example? Is this a real issue?

UPDATE:
Additional errors I found

```
622021-10-08 14:48:25,390   INFO web_log.py:206 -- 172.26.78.141 [08/Oct/2021:21:48:25 +0000] "GET /logs/worker-145e900539c0580c2b0b1d620966d566ef15897d5195d45386d1635e-01000000-5988.err HTTP/1.1" 200 211 "http://127.0.0.1:8265/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"
632021-10-08 14:48:26,396   ERROR web_protocol.py:393 -- Unhandled exception
64Traceback (most recent call last):
65  File "/home/anthony/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/hello-ray-O1YdFran-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 485, in start
66    resp, reset = await task
67  File "/home/anthony/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/hello-ray-O1YdFran-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 440, in _handle_request
68    reset = await self.finish_response(request, resp, start_time)
69  File "/home/anthony/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/hello-ray-O1YdFran-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 591, in finish_response
70    await prepare_meth(request)
71  File "/home/anthony/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/hello-ray-O1YdFran-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_fileresponse.py", line 241, in prepare
72    return await self._sendfile(request, fobj, offset, count)
73  File "/home/anthony/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/hello-ray-O1YdFran-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_fileresponse.py", line 96, in _sendfile
74    await loop.sendfile(transport, fobj, offset, count)
75  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1120, in sendfile
76    return await self._sendfile_native(transport, file,
77  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 578, in _sendfile_native
78    return await self.sock_sendfile(transp._sock, file, offset, count,
79  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 836, in sock_sendfile
80    self._check_sendfile_params(sock, file, offset, count)
81  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 889, in _check_sendfile_params
82    raise ValueError(
83ValueError: count must be a positive integer (got 0)
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide synthetic data for csv files?

Comment: Also, what's the version of Ray you are using?

Comment: I am also receiving this ValueError that you mentioned last when a second worker is initialized at the beginning of the script. Then, this worker will be rendered unusable, but, curiously enough, only until the first worker finishes the first task. Then, both work fine. I could not find a solution thus far.

Comment: A few ray versions have come out since this post. I didn't actually do anything to fix the problem though, I just restarted my laptop and it seemed to fix itself. It definitely only happened on WSL for me though.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a ulimit issue. Ray tends to use a lot of open files, so you'll need to bump that limit up.

When running your script, you should do `ulimit -n 65535; python script.py` or `ulimit -n 65535; ray start --head` depending on how you start ray.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be true. Just tested with `ulimit -n == 65535` and I'm getting the same message.

Comment: can you post the error message? In your original post it says you have an error message that says "Current maximum open files is 4096.". Does it still say that after you update the ulimit?

Comment: It does say that in one of the logs, but there are other logs that say "This may be a bug since objects " (shared above) as well. There are just so many log files produced. The output I'm referring to is the output from the main python script upon failure, which is the same as the first message in the original post. I'll have to look at the dozens of log files again to see if there are any new errors. I can't see any easy way to get errors from across the system in the dashboard.

Comment: Added an additional error message from the dashboard agent, but that might be a ui bug or something.